# How to filter model by foreign key field of FK field?

Tags: python, django, filter

I have model 'Employee':

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    id          = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastname    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    end_user_id = models.CharField(max_length=8, help_text=u"Please enter the end user id, like ABC1WZ1")
    history     = HistoricalRecords()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + self.lastname
```

Employee can be a manager, so I also have model 'Manager':

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Employee,   verbose_name='manager', on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.manager .name + ' ' + self.manager .lastname
```

And my main model 'MissForm':

```
class MissForm(models.Model):
    id                  = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    auto_inc_id         = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sender              = models.ForeignKey(Employee,           verbose_name='sender',              on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager,       verbose_name='Manager',        on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='+',  blank=True, null=True )
    status_flag         = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
```

I am trying to get all instances of MissForm model where manager is a current logined user and `status_flag=2`( in views.py):

```
login_user_id = request.user.username.upper() # returns smth like ABC1WZ1
forms = MissForm.objects.filter(status_flag=2, manager__manager__end_user_id=login_user_id)
```

But it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error, it's look like such instances aren't exist but they are.

Comment: The query is correct, so likely the data is not correct. You convert the username to uppercase, which also is weird: why not a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model?

Comment: Sorry, I am inserting another variable to django template. Everything is ok now.

Comment: I am using uppercase, because real user can login in 2 ways: abc1wz1 and ABC1WZ1. So i am trying to eliminate this problem.

Comment: but that is a problem with logging in to the correct user. You should not "move" that to the filtering part, since that will make it an awful lot harder.